# Using a for loop, how do I populate a lambda where condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, lambda

I have a list of dynamic data. I would like to loop through the list to create a where clause.  How do I do that?

```
IQueryable<MyObject> result = originalData;
foreach (var item in Years)
{
    result = input.Where(x => x.Year == item).AsQueryable();
}
```

2013 should have 30 and 2014 should have 18. My result only gives 18 when it should be 48. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I should mention I know I am overwriting the result. I tried += and I get the error that '+=' cannot be applied to operands of IQueryable(MyObject> and IQueryable(MyObject>

Comment: did result += expresion work? or what are you doing with you result?

Comment: You are replacing the result from the first loop with the result from the second loop.

Comment: result += input.Where(x => x.Year == item).AsQueryable();

Comment: You are closing over a loop variable. By the time lambda got executed, loop var takes it's final value. In order to avoid this, copy llop variable to local, e.g on fitst line in loop body `var year = item`

Comment: "2013 should have 30 and 2014 should have 18". What data structure do you want these stored in?

Comment: @BenAaronson, I believe by that OP meant 30 and 18 rows/records.

Comment: @Habib Right, but stored how? A `Dictionary<Year, IEnumerable<Item>>`? (with `Year` and `Item` being whatever the actual types for those things are)

Comment: I tried += and got an error. I know I am overwriting the results. See edit

Comment: @MrM, `+=` should not work with IQueryable.

Comment: For me the question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop, you can do:

```
IQueryable<MyObject> result = input.Where(x=> Years.Contains(x.Year));
```

Currently your `result` is holding the last value of your loop. So suppose your last value in `Years` is 2014, then you get back 18 rows against it, the previous rows are overwritten in the iteration.